# How can I bypass the 429-error from www.instagram.com?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, instagram, http-status-code-429

I'm soliciting you today because I've got a problem with selenium.
My goal is to make a fully automated bot that creates an account with parsed details (mail, pass, birth date...) So far, I've managed to almost create the bot (I just need to access Gmail and get the confirmation code).

My problem is here, because I've tried a lot of things, I have a `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 429 ()`
So, I guess, Instagram is blocking me.
how could I bypass this?

Comment: I'm surprised you're getting this with Selenium, are you using `requests` module? You're going to need to research Instagram's request limits (not sure if that's public info) and build your bot accordingly. Most of the time you will be able to try again after a certain amount of time (Google Translate resets theirs at midnight I believe). But I would ultimately look for a different method because if you trip that when you run your bot too often it's gonna be a pain

Comment: FYI this also happens if **other** people in your IP range are doing mass requests

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the description of the HTTP error code. You are being blocked because you made too many requests in a short time.

Reduce the rate at which your bot makes requests and see if that helps. As far as I know there's no way to "bypass" this check by the server.

Check if the response header has a `Retry-After` value to tell you when you can try again.

Answer (score 1):

It is because your IP is blocked. I had the same issue, then opened up  NordVPN and tried to login again - worked fine. I could turn the VPN off and had access.

Comment: I don't think this is too related to the question and it looks a bit like NordVPN advertisement. How are you sure their IP is blocked?

Answer (score 0):

Status code of `429` means that you've bombarded Instagram's server too many times ,and that is why Instagram has blocked your ip.

This is done mainly to prevent from DDOS attacks.

Best thing would be to try after some time ( there might be a `Retry-After` header in the response).

Also, increase the time interval between each request and set the specific count of  number of requests made within a specified time (let's say 1 hr).

Answer (score 0):

`Retry-After` header is the best practice. However, there's no such response header in this scenario.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please consider providing some source code to support explanation. It helps to understand the resolution.